# How to use underscores as word boundary for moving cursor?

Tags: syntax-table

Python mode annoyingly sets underscore (`_`) to be part of a word, making editing very tedious.

How can one reset this to Emacs's original behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Simply call the function `py-underscore-word-syntax-p-off` in your config file:

```lisp
(use-package python-mode
  :ensure t

  :config
  (py-underscore-word-syntax-p-off))
```

*Edited: use helper function instead of setting `py-underscore-word-syntax-p-off` programmatically.*

Comment: it doesn't work in `:config` because despite is defined as variable it's later set by `defcustom` ([look here](https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode/-/blob/master/python-mode.el#L2511)). So it may not work in another configuration if its value taken from there differs from your `:init` value. You should dig what the setter does and configure the value properly (wherever it'll be, I don't write python).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I don't think that a user should read source code in order to configure a package. Anyway, I have found a helper function and changed my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the syntax of character `_` to *symbol* syntax (`"_"`):

```lisp
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "_" python-mode-syntax-table) ; "_" means symbol syntax
```

Or change it to some other syntax class (other than word syntax: `"w"`). For example, change it to punctuation syntax:

```lisp
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "." python-mode-syntax-table) ; "." means punctuation syntax
```

See the Elisp manual, node [Syntax Table Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Table-Functions.html).

Comment: Thanks! To do this automatically, add this to the .emacs file: `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook  (lambda ()
     (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "_" python-mode-syntax-table)))`